# bootstrap table - call to server side is not triggered

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am trying to learn how to use the bootstrap table plugin, found here. 
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/

The specific example I'm trying to mimic is found here:
http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html

My html code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6h5sqs9d/

On the server side, I have the following in my cgi-bin/widgets file:

```
    r,s = 200, "{'id':1,'Name':'test  name','code':'12345','available':'yes'}"

    print ("Status:" .. r )
    print ("Content-Type: text/html")
    print ()
    print (s)
```

I know this page is working because when i navigate directly to it, i see the json output in my browser. 
But I guess I'm lacking in understanding how the client side code calls the server.  I see that the table has a property called data-url:

```
  data-url="/cgi-bin/widgets"
```

But what else is needed to trigger the retrieval of the data from backend?
I'm currently making my way through the documentation as well, but I haven't found anything just yet. I know the server is not being called because when I check F12 - Network... the GET request doesn't have the cgi-bin/widgets listed.

thanks.

Comment: found one problem.  I was loading the boostrap scripts before jquery.  I just changed the order and now I actually see the basic framework for the table appear.  and i see that it's now calling the server

Comment: Did you check your console? If you forget to include jQuery/included jQuery in the wrong order, you probably would have had a nice `$ is not a function` error.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up the order of the  I was including.

```
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

has been changed to:

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
```